# Iterator over map with uncopyable types

Tags: c++, iterator

I am trying to implement my own map type and I want an `iterator` for this map. My understanding is that the `value_type` of this iterator should be `pair<const K, V>` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). Now, the iterator's `operator*` is supposed to return a reference to such a pair. I think this means that I need to store a member in my iterator called `current_val` so that I can return a reference to it. My question is how to get this to work when `V` is not copyable. So my implementation looks something like:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class Map {
  class Iterator {
   public:
    pair<const K, V>& operator*() { return current_val_; }

    Iterator& operator++() {
      ++index_;
      // Now I need to update current_val_;
      current_val_ = std::make_pair(keys_[i], vals_[i]);
    }

   private:
    pair<const K, V> current_val_;
    int index_ = 0;
    K* keys_;
    V* vals_;
  };
 private:
   K* keys_;
   V* vals_;
};
```

In this code snippet updating `current_val_` doesn't work because it is copying the value into `current_val_` but `V` doesn't support copying.

One possible solution would be to store the data as `std::pair<K, V>*` instead of storing the keys and values separately, but unfortunately I can't do that.

Comment: `current_val` should be a pointer (or a reference) but not a copy, otherwise modifying your container through the iterator would only modify the copy and not the actual one it's supposed to refer to. And it would also *solve the issue of uncopyable types.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, you mean `pair<K, V>*` or `pair<K*, V*>`

Comment: a pointer to the element in the map is a `pair<cosnt K,V>*`.

Comment: It is difficult to provide a complete answer, because the code you posted is incomplete. Where do you actually store the elements of the map?

Comment: I am wrapping a different data structure and don't have access to the underlying data.

Comment: of course you have access to the underlying data. How would you get a copy otherwise?

Comment: what is `GetKey` and `GetValue` ?

Comment: OK, I'll update the question with more details to the question.

Comment: frankly your design is off from the start. A `std::map` or generally a map that can offer iterators to `std::pair<const K,V>` stores `std::pair<const K,V>` as elements. You cannot provide the user a reference to a `std::pair<const K,V>` when there is no `std::pair<const K,V>` in the first place

Comment: or worded differently, why do you store the elements as `K*` and `V*` (rather than `std::pair<const K,V>`) ? If that is a fixed requirement it will be more difficult, but can be done via some proxies

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying that `iterator` by design must expose the underlying storage of my data? Is it bad to return a `pair<K*, V*>` instead in which case it won't matter how the data is stored I can just construct a pair and return it?

Comment: @BenjyKessler "so you're saying that iterator by design must expose the underlying storage of my data" not necessarily. Usually iterators do provide references to the elments in the container. You can take a look at `std::vector<bool>`. Its a case where `std::vector<bool>::reference` is some proxy because it cannot be an actual reference to the underlying data. It is possible, but it is a lot more complicated. Thats why I was asking if changing your data type to `std::pair<const K,V>` is an option or not

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I'll take a look at std::vector<bool>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a copy. The iterator should provide some means to modify the element in the container, not a copy of that element.

As you are bound to storing the data as `K*` and `V*` you cannot simply return a reference to a `std::pair<const K,V>` because there is no such element to begin with.

You can take a look at `std::vector<bool>` as an example of `container::reference` (the type returned from the iterators dereference) not actually being a reference to the element, but some proxy type. This proxy type should be designed to behave like a `std::pair<const K,V>&`.

Your iterators merely need to store the index into the member arrays, and either a pointer to those arrays or to the whole map. Then you need to use a proxy that implements the methods you want to support:

```
class Iterator {
public:
    proxy operator*() { return *this; }
    Iterator& operator++() {
        ++index_;
        return *this;
    }

private:
   int index_ = 0;
   K* keys_;
   V* vals_;
};

struct proxy {
      K* key;
      V* val;
      proxy(const Iterator& it) : key(it.keys_+it.index), val(it.vals_+it.index) {}
      // make it look like a std::pair<const K,V>
      const K& first() { return *key; }
      V& second() { return *val; }
      // enable assignment of std::pair<const K,V>
      proxy& operator=(const std::pair<const K,V>&);
      // comparison with std::pair<const K,V>
      bool operator==(const std::pair<const K,V>&);
      // ... etc ...
};
```

Not tested, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Cool, I'll try to play around with this. The next step will be getting structured bindings to work with this :)